# PyQt5 update values in editable QTableView

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtableview

I have an editable `QTableView` with a range of *x* values, their squares and their cubes.

[image]

Is there a way that if any value is changed a signal is launched to update the rest of the cells in the same row?

For instance, if I change the value *x* = 2 by *x* = 5, then somehow to know that the change has happened and the code has to update the rest of the values in the row.

[image]

I paste in a sample of my original code in case it helps.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, Qt


class PandasModelEditable(QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, data):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self._data = data

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, parnet=None):
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                return str(self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()])

            column_count = self.columnCount()
            for column in range(0, column_count):
                if (index.column() == column and role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole):
                    return Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter

        return None

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data.columns[col]
        
        return None

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return False
        
        if role != Qt.EditRole:
            return False
        
        row = index.row()
        if row < 0 or row >= len(self._data.values):
            return False
        
        column = index.column()
        if column < 0 or column >= self._data.columns.size:
            return False
        
        self._data.values[row][column] = value
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
        return True
    
    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    import sys
    import pandas as pd
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView

    df = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(5),
                       'x²': [i**2 for i in range(5)],
                       'x³': [i**3 for i in range(5)]
                       })

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    model = PandasModelEditable(df)
    view = QTableView()
    view.setModel(model)
    view.resize(350, 200)
view.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**EDITED**

Since the kind answers are not 100 % helpful and I populate the `QtableView` with a `pandas` `DataFrame`, I have opened a [new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62812459/synchronize-pandas-dataframe-with-pyqt5-qtableview) with a new question.

Comment: Could the user change *any* column, or just the first one?

Comment: You can change any column.

Answer (score 0):

I noted for you the lines in which I made changes.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, Qt


class PandasModelEditable(QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, data):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self._data = data

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, parnet=None):
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                return str(self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()])

            column_count = self.columnCount()
            for column in range(0, column_count):
                if (index.column() == column and role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole):
                    return Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter

        return None

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data.columns[col]
        return None

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if not value.isdigit():                                               # +++
            return False                                                      # +++
    
        if not index.isValid():
            return False
        
        if role != Qt.EditRole:
            return False
        
        row = index.row()
        if row < 0 or row >= len(self._data.values):
            return False
        
        column = index.column()
        if column < 0 or column >= self._data.columns.size:
            return False
        
        self._data.values[row][column] = value

        self._data.values[row][1] = int(value)**2                             # +++
        self._data.values[row][2] = int(value)**3                             # +++
        
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
        return True
    
    def flags(self, index):
#        return Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable

        fl = QAbstractTableModel.flags(self, index)                           # +++
        if index.column() == 0:                                               # +++
            fl |= Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable  # +++
        return fl                                                             # +++              


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    import sys
    import pandas as pd
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView

    df = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(5),
                       'x²': [i**2 for i in range(5)],
                       'x³': [i**3 for i in range(5)]
                       })

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    model = PandasModelEditable(df)
    view = QTableView()
    view.setModel(model)
    view.resize(350, 200)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer @S. Nick, although I have two questions: 1. Why does it only work with ints? In a real case they can also be floats. 2. It works fine with the first column, but I can't change the values in the other columns, e. g. if x² = 36, then x = 6 and x³ = 216.

Comment: I have changed the dataframe to 
`vals = [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3] \ df = pd.DataFrame({'x': vals, 'x²': [val**2 for val in vals], 'x³': [val**3 for val in vals]})` 
and it only works if I change *x* to an int, but not to a float.