# Synchronize pandas DataFrame with PyQt5 QTableView

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyqt5, qtableview

I have an editable `QTableView` which reads the values from a `pandas` `DataFrame`.

[image]

What I'm looking for is that when I change the value of one cell, the `pandas` `DataFrame` synchronizes automatically. The aim is to continue operating with the updated `DataFrame`, for example, to update the values of the other rows of the `DataFrame` and refresh the `QTableView`.

[image]

I've seen that there are similar questions in the forum, but since `MVC` is new to me and I'm not a professional programmer, I find it hard to understand the solutions and I haven't managed to implement them in my code.

I paste here the code I have so far.

**run.py**

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableView

from cnt_init_values import CntInitialValues

from tablemodel_editable import PandasModel


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
                    
        # Packages.
        # ---------
        self.pd = pd
        
        # Instancies of class.
        # --------------------
        self.cnt_init_val = CntInitialValues(self)
        
        # Objects of the aplication.
        # --------------------------
        self.df_table = pd.DataFrame()
        
        # PyQt5 objects.
        # --------------
        self.tableview = QTableView()
        
        # Add initial values to QTableView and show them.
        # -----------------------------------------------
        self.df_table = self.cnt_init_val.dataframe_initial()
        self.cnt_init_val.initial_values(self.df_table)

    # PyQt5 outputs.
    # ==============
    
    def table_output(self, df):
        
        print(self.df_table)
        
        model = PandasModel(df)
        self.tableview.setModel(model)
        self.tableview.resize(350, 250)
        self.tableview.show()

        
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**cnt_init_values.py**

```
from initialvalues import InitialValues

class CntInitialValues:
    """Controller"""
    
    def __init__(self, window):
        
        self.w = window
        
    def dataframe_initial(self):
        
        d_initial_values = InitialValues.d_INITIAL_VALUES
        df_initial = self.w.pd.DataFrame(d_initial_values)
        
        return df_initial
        
    def initial_values(self, df):
        
        self.w.table_output(df)
```

**initialvalues.py**

```
class InitialValues:
    
    vals = [float(i) for i in range(6)]
    
    d_INITIAL_VALUES = {
        'x': vals,
        'x²': [val**2 for val in vals],
        'x³': [val**3 for val in vals]
        }
```

**tablemodel_editable.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, Qt


class PandasModel(QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, data):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self._data = data

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, parnet=None):
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():

            if role == Qt.DisplayRole:

                return str(self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()])

            column_count = self.columnCount()
            
            for column in range(0, column_count):
                
                if (index.column() == column and role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole):

                    return Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter

        return None

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data.columns[col]
        return None

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return False
        
        if role != Qt.EditRole:
            return False
        
        row = index.row()
        
        if row < 0 or row >= len(self._data.values):
            return False
        
        column = index.column()
        
        if column < 0 or column >= self._data.columns.size:
            
            return False
        
        self._data.iloc[row][column] = value
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
        
        return True

    def flags(self, index):
        flags = super(self.__class__,self).flags(index)
        flags |= Qt.ItemIsEditable
        flags |= Qt.ItemIsSelectable
        flags |= Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        flags |= Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled
        flags |= Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled
        
        return flags
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is so simple that I don't understand it. If someone could just explain to me what's going on.

I point out the changes I've made in `run.py`:

**run.py edited**

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        uic.loadUi('table.ui', self)  # --- Loading from Qt Designer. ---
        
        # Packages.
        # ---------
        self.pd = pd
        
        # Instancies of class.
        # --------------------
        self.cnt_init_val = CntInitialValues(self)
                    
        # Attributes of the instance.
        # ---------------------------
        self.df_table = pd.DataFrame()
        self.model = ''  # --- Instance variable for model. ---
        
        # PyQt5 objects.
        # --------------
        self.tableview = self.tableView
        self.btn_print_df = self.pushButtonPrintDataFrame  # --- pushButton to print DataFrame. ---
        
        # Add initial values to QTableView and show them.
        # -----------------------------------------------
        self.df_table = self.cnt_init_val.dataframe_initial()
        self.cnt_init_val.initial_values(self.df_table)
        
        # Events.
        # -------
        self.btn_print_df.clicked.connect(self.dataframe_output) # --- pushButton prints DataFrame. ---

    # PyQt5 outputs.
    # ==============
    
    def table_output(self, df):
        
        print('\nInitial DataFrame:')
        print(self.df_table)
        
        self.model = PandasModel(df)
        self.tableview.setModel(self.model)
        self.tableview.show()
    
    # Terminal outputs.  # --- DaraFrame output. ---
    # =================
        
    def dataframe_output(self):
        
        print('\nUpdated DataFrame:')
        print(self.df_table)
```

Firstly, when the app is executed:

[image]

```
Initial DataFrame:
     x    x²     x³
0  0.0   0.0    0.0
1  1.0   1.0    1.0
2  2.0   4.0    8.0
3  3.0   9.0   27.0
4  4.0  16.0   64.0
5  5.0  25.0  125.0
```

After changing some values in the table:

[image]

```
Updated DataFrame:
       x    x²      x³
0  999.0   0.0     0.0
1    1.0   1.0     1.0
2    2.0   4.0     8.0
3    3.0   9.0    27.0
4    4.0  16.0    64.0
5    5.0  25.0  1111.0
```

Now I have to work with the DataFrame to make the values of the rows consistent, but that's another question.