# How to accept only numeric values as input for the QTableWidget ? Disable the alphabet keys

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to validate the Qtablewidget input in each cell. How to accept only numeric value.For Example Like this QLineEdit widget.
I am to the the PyQt5 GUI programming.
I want to create a application to accept only numeric values and want to do further calculation.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidget, QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidgetItem, QFileDialog,qApp, QAction,QStyledItemDelegate,QLineEdit
from pandas import DataFrame
from numpy.linalg import inv
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRegExp
from PyQt5.QtGui import QRegExpValidator
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
import sqlite3 
import os
import re
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
   
    def submit(self):
     
        rowCount = self.tableWidgetInput.rowCount()
        columnCount = self.tableWidgetInput.columnCount()
        max_sum = 0
        global TMatrix,Ri,Ci,RiplusCi,RiMinusCi,inputArray_2D
        if (rowCount==columnCount):
            size=rowCount
            print("The size of the matrxi is %d * %d "%(size,size))
            print("The Given  matrxi is",  "SUM of Row" )
            rowData =[]
            
            for row in range(size):
                for column in range (size):
                        widegetItem = self.tableWidgetInput.item(row,column)

                        if(widegetItem and widegetItem.text):
                            rowData.append(float(widegetItem.text()) )
                        else:
                            rowData.append('NULL')
            print(rowData)
            inputArray = np.array(rowData,dtype=np.float64)  ###convert the list into numpy array.
            print(inputArray)
            size_rowdata = len(rowData)
            print("The total number of elemets are ",size_rowdata)
            inputArray_2D = np.reshape(inputArray, (rowCount, columnCount))   ### Reshape the numpy array into 2D
            print(inputArray_2D)
            sumofCol = np.sum(inputArray_2D,axis = 0,dtype='float')  ###find the sum of Column
            sumofRow = np.sum(inputArray_2D,axis = 1,dtype='float') ### find the sum of Row     
            maxInCol = np.amax(sumofCol)
            maxInRows = np.amax(sumofRow)
            print( "The Sum of Column is : ",sumofCol)
            print( "The Sum of Row is :",sumofRow)
            print( "The Maximum value in the  Column is :",maxInCol)
            print( "The Maximum value in the  Row is  : ",maxInRows)  
                   
        else:
            print("The input  is not a Square matrix")
            print("Data is not Submitted Sucessfully")

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1500, 1200)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.tableWidgetInput = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidgetInput.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 90, 1049, 520))
        self.tableWidgetInput.setObjectName("tableWidgetInput")
        self.tableWidgetInput.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidgetInput.setRowCount(2)
        self.pushButton_submit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_submit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 625, 131, 51))
        self.pushButton_submit.setObjectName("pushButton_submit")                                        
        self.pushButton_submit.clicked.connect(self.submit)                                                    
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget) 
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton_submit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Submit"))
      
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How to accept only numeric values here?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62696878/pyqt5-update-values-in-editable-qtableview/62703059#62703059

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution is to set the validator to the editor created by the delegate:

```
class NumericDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = super(NumericDelegate, self).createEditor(parent, option, index)
        if isinstance(editor, QLineEdit):
            reg_ex = QRegExp("[0-9]+.?[0-9]{,2}")
            validator = QRegExpValidator(reg_ex, editor)
            editor.setValidator(validator)
        return editor
```

```
delegate = NumericDelegate(self.tablewidget)
self.tablewidget.setItemDelegate(delegate)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.                                                                                                                        
                        if isinstance(editor, QLineEdit):
                       NameError: name 'QLineEdit' is not defined..                                                                        
 if I change the the QLineEdit into QTableWidget   
rowData.append(float(widegetItem.text()) )
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'tr'

Comment: @SuganthiGanesh Have you imported QLineEdit: `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit`?

Comment: Yes . I already import it. still the cell accepts the alphabets and cannot append it into list  further

Comment: @SuganthiGanesh I do not understand you, according to what you indicate that regex towards the QLineEdit of your example will accept what you wanted

Comment: Im sorry for the inconvenience. the  reg_ex = QRegExp("[0-9]+.?[0-9]{,2}") states that only numeric data right? why it  accepts the alphabets too?

Comment: @SuganthiGanesh I have not tested the regex since I trust that what is indicated in your post is true: *For Example Like this QLineEdit widget.*

Comment: ,Thank you for your time.  Is the there any way to check the cellEntered() is numeric without delegates?

Comment: @SuganthiGanesh I do not understand you, if you want more help you must provide a [mre]. bye

Comment: Kindly Check the post. I have added the code as per the  minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @SuganthiGanesh change `if(widegetItem and widegetItem.text):` to `if widegetItem and widegetItem.text():`

Comment: @ eyllanesc   Thank you so much . It's working now..

Comment: @SuganthiGanesh If my answer helped you then don't forget to mark as correct, if you don't know how to do it then check the [tour]